# Should I disable Knex.js connection pool in HA setup?

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, knex.js, pgpool

I have a High Availability setup where data flows as such:

```
... <-> Objection.js <-> Knex.js (pool) <-> Pgpool-II (pool) <-> PostgreSQL Cluster
```

As you see, the connection pool is being managed in two places right now - Knex.js and Pgpool-II. I am wondering if I really need both or can I just disable Knex.js pooling altogether with `pool: {min: 0, max: 0}` and let Pgpool-II do all the work? Thank you.

Comment: same issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63263087/whats-the-difference-between-orm-query-builder-library-connection-pool-size-and